# Action bar App title name wasn't displayed in my applicaton

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I didn't know why my action bar title name was suddenly disappears.But icon was displayed at the top of the screeen.But Application name wasn't displayed at the top of the screen.

Below I am posted codes related to that.

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.activity;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements
         VideoListFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener,ActionBar.OnNavigationListener   {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add channel list array to actionbar spinner
                Context context = getActionBar().getThemedContext();
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.channel_name, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
                list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // remove actionbar title and add spinner to actionbar
                getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
                getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list,  this);

    //  position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

        Log.v("position", position + "");
        appData = ((GemsApplication) this.getApplication()).getAppData();

        AppPreferences.setAppPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        actionabar = getActionBar();
        actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //  actionabar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                actionabar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }
        };
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<application
android:name="com.sit.loco.app.GemsApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
    android:name="com.sit.loco.activity.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>

<application>
```

**In res/menu/home.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menuShare" 
        android:title="@string/share_it" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share" 
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menuRate" 
        android:title="@string/rate_it" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_good" 
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menuAbout" 
        android:title="@string/about" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_info" 
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
</menu>
```

I didn't know how to solve this.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); and actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(ture);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

It removes the title from the action bar. Either change it to:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

or simply remove it completely.